# Full Text search on a Varbinary Column - Is it possible to use a mime type rather than a file extension as my Type Column?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I am setting up full text search on an existing database. We have Document table with the following schema:

```
ID int Not Null,
Data varbinary(max) Not Null
MimeType varchar Not Null
```

I want to use full text search on the data column, using the mimetype to specify the document type.

I was hoping it would be possible to register new types into whatever tables are used when you use the view `sys.fulltext_document_types`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it isn't possible. IFilters are mapped to a document extension. A new column has to be added and populated.